# List of pointers in cuda?

Tags: list, pointers, cuda

```
__global__ void finalImageGathering(float3 *lists[]) {
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    float3 test;
    for(int i = 0; i<Blah; i++)
        test += lists[i][y * width + x];
}
```

Is it possible to have a list of pointers to diffrent float3 lists, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: You might want to properly format this first and clarify what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, CUDA imposes no special limits on pointer indirection for anything other than function pointers (and that limitation is mostly gone on recent hardware too). What is more complex is allocating the memory for such an array of device pointers, and copying it to and from host memory, if you need to.